# Soyez les premiers à être "informé" ou "informés" ?

Tags: grammaire, accord, orthographe, auxiliaires, attributs

On a eu un doute avec notre équipe sur l'orthographe d'une phrase:

dit-on:

> Soyez les premiers à être informé?

ou bien:

> Soyez les premiers à être informés?

Merci

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Informés* bien sûr !

La règle est de toujours faire l'accord avec le sujet en genre et en nombre quand l'auxiliaire est le verbe être et le verbe n'est pas pronominal.

Comment: es ce que la phrase suivante est correcte : " Merci d’être informé que j'ai reçu ce matin un appel ......"

Comment: @samsami Elle n'est pas très naturelle. En ce qui concerne la grammaire, tout dépend d'à qui elle s'adresse...

Comment: @samsami J'ai l'impression que c'est un calque de l'anglais "Please be advised" ou d'une autre langue. Un meilleur choix serait "Prenez note que".

Comment: Désolé pour le downvote sur cette réponse en passant, j'avais mal lu la question hier et je ne peux plus retirer mon vote tant que le post n'est pas modifié

Comment: @domino Ça y est, j'ai légèrement modifié ma réponse. Mon "score" va pouvoir se relever, il avait pris une sacrée claque ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Sois/Soyez le premier à être informé.
> 2. Sois/Soyez la première à être informée.
> 3. Soyez les premiers à être informés.
> 4. Soyez les premières à être informées.

où

1. Sujet masculin (tutoiement/vouvoiement).
2. Sujet féminin (idem).
3. Sujets (dont un, au moins, masculin).
4. Sujets (tous féminins).

Informer: Infinitif => Être informé(e)(s) : *Infinitif passé passif* (à savoir, celui de la voix passive).

https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic18051-infinitif-passif.html

Answer (score 0):

informéS
L'adjectif s'accorde en genre et en nombre avec le nom (qu'il qualifie)

Comment: Il s'agit ici d'un participe passé, pas d'un adjectif...

Comment: Effectivement 

Subjonctif
Présent

que je sois informé
que tu sois informé
qu'il soit informé
que nous soyons informés
que vous soyez informés
qu'ils soient informés

Comment: En l’occurrence il s'agit ici d'un impératif.

Comment: @Laurent S. : Oui!, je le crois aussi. Maintenant, en toute rigueur observable, on peut laisser le bénéfice du doute à Imene. Un subjonctif employé en impératif de politesse. Cela resterait un subjonctif. J'y crois peu dans le cas présent mais... cela reste possible. Il y aurait un *je vous prie* après... que la cause serait entendue.